# Get the additions and drops for each person by year in R

Tags: r, function, group-by

I'm trying to get the additions and drops for each person by year in R (examples is as follows). I was trying to write a function which returns what each person adds and drops as well as the number of person adds and drops by year. Say in this sample Mark Add = 0, Add_act =N/A, Drop = 2, Drop_act = c("Basketball", "Volleyball"). Using "for loops" is my instinct reaction, any suggestions on how is more appropriate to design the algorithm?

Thanks,
Anne

```
Year    Name    Activity
2010    Mark    Tennis
2010    Mark    Swim
2010    Mark    Basketball
2010    Mark    Volleyball
2010    Tom     Swim
2010    Rachale Tennis
2010    Rachale Waterball
2010    Rachale Yoga
2010    Mary    Volleyball
2010    Mary    Yoga
2010    Kim     Waterball
2011    Mark    Tennis
2011    Mark    Swim
2011    Tom     Volleyball
2011    Tom     Waterball
2011    Tom     Swim
2011    Rachale Tennis
2011    Rachale Waterball
2011    Rachale Yoga
2011    Rachale Swim
2011    Mary    Volleyball
2011    Jerry   Basketball
```

The outcome I'm expecting looks like this:

Year    Name    Add Add_act                                         Drop Drop_act
2010    Mark    4   "Tennis", "Swim", "Basketball", "Volleyball"    0   NA
2010    Tom 1   "Swim"                                          0   NA
2010    Rachale 3   "Tennis",  "Waterball", "Yoga"                  0   NA
2010    Mary    2   "Volleyball", "Yoga"                            0   NA
2010    Kim     1   "Waterball"                                     0   NA
2011    Mark    0   NA                                              1   "Basketball"
2011    Tom     1   "Waterball"                                     0   NA
2011    Rachale 1   "Swim"                                          0   NA
2011    Mary    0   NA                                              1   "Yoga"
2011    Jerry   1   "Basketball"                                    0   NA
2011    Kim     0   NA                                              1   "Waterball"

Comment: So someone drops or adds things by having them show up one year and not the next, or vice versa?

Comment: This could happen as well, will have new comers and someone dropping out of the sample. So basically I was trying to catch the changes for each year for the number of additions and drops as well as a individual, year level of string saying which one get added and dropped.

Comment: So, do you want a function that returns the example stuff you posted above (like in my answer), or do you want something that gives you...? Something else? If you could post what your hypothetical output would look like, it would help.

Comment: Edited some records of the example and added the desired outcome. Still struggling about how to format the data though... Thanks

Comment: I've updated my question to address needing to get multiple outputs. It currently produces a list of lists using `mapply`.

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. Be sure to accept an answer for the question and to upvote the ones that were helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED: Okay, so, you will need to use loops now that I understand your desire to aggregate across the whole dataset. However, you can do so using the `*apply` functions in R, which will also put your output into a nice list.

We can use the simple function I wrote originally, with a minor modification that adds in the name and year (just for ease of interpreting the output).

The function takes an input data frame, the person you want to check, and the year you are evaluating. It then forms two vectors, one of the current year's activities and one of the previous year's activities. Then, we just use the `%in%` operator to subset each of those vectors to get additions and subtractions, and find the total using `length`.

Using `expand.grid`, we'll get all possible combinations of year and individual in the sample data. Then, using `mapply`, we can create the outputs from those combinations. The result is a list of lists (which I used because a data frame is not sensible in this context, since the activities added or dropped is of varying length).

I put your data into a text file that I read in using `read.csv`.

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df_example <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/trehman/Desktop/input.txt",header = F)
names(df_example) <- c("Year","Name","Activity")

func_find_changes <- function(data,person,year) {

    curryr_acts <- data[data$Name == person
                        & data$Year == year,"Activity"]
    prevyr_acts <- data[data$Name == person
                        & data$Year == year - 1,"Activity"]

    added_acts <- curryr_acts[!(curryr_acts %in% prevyr_acts)]
    dropped_acts <- prevyr_acts[!(prevyr_acts %in% curryr_acts)]
    n_add <- length(added_acts)
    n_drop <- length(dropped_acts)
    return(list(Person = person,
                Year = year,
                Add = n_add,
                Add_act = added_acts,
                Drop = n_drop,
                Drop_act = dropped_acts))
}

# Create all combinations to check
df_nameyears <- expand.grid(unique(df_example$Year),
                            unique(df_example$Name),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Use mapply() to get them
lst_changes <- mapply(FUN = func_find_changes,
                      year = df_nameyears$Var1,
                      person = df_nameyears$Var2,
                      MoreArgs = list(data = df_example),
                      SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to go through the final outcome but I can see this will maybe help you or someone else get started. The idea is to split the datasets by the individuals, then index the years and find co-occurrence frequencies

#### Also, please use `dput` so we can recreate the data easily... here's what I did:

```
a <- textConnection('Year    Name    Activity
2010    Mark    Tennis
2010    Mark    Swim
2010    Mark    Basketball
2010    Mark    Volleyball
2010    Tom     Swim
2010    Rachale Tennis
2010    Rachale Waterball
2010    Rachale Yoga
2010    Mary    Volleyball
2010    Mary    Yoga
2011    Mark    Tennis
2011    Mark    Swim
2011    Tom     Volleyball
2011    Tom     Waterball
2011    Tom     Swim
2011    Rachale Tennis
2011    Rachale Waterball
2011    Rachale Yoga
2011    Rachale Swim
2011    Mary    Volleyball')%>% read.table %>% {
    colnames(.) <- as.character(.[1,])
    .[-1,]
}


lapply(split(a, a$Name), function(i){
    counts <- count(i, Year)
        n_change <- as.numeric(counts[nrow(counts),2] - counts[1,2])
        if(n_change < 0){
            add <- 0
            drop <- n_change * -1
        }else {
            add <- n_change
            drop <- 0
        }
    check_act <- acast(i, Activity ~ Year, value.var = "Year")
    list(add = add, drop = drop, adply(check_act, 2, is.na))
})


# $Mark
# $Mark$add
# [1] 0
# 
# $Mark$drop
# [1] 2
# 
# $Mark[[3]]
#     X1 Basketball  Swim Tennis Volleyball
# 1 2010      FALSE FALSE  FALSE      FALSE
# 2 2011       TRUE FALSE  FALSE       TRUE
# 
# 
# $Mary
# $Mary$add
# [1] 0
# 
# $Mary$drop
# [1] 1
# 
# $Mary[[3]]
#     X1 Volleyball  Yoga
# 1 2010      FALSE FALSE
# 2 2011      FALSE  TRUE
# 
# 
# $Rachale
# $Rachale$add
# [1] 1
# 
# $Rachale$drop
# [1] 0
# 
# $Rachale[[3]]
#     X1  Swim Tennis Waterball  Yoga
# 1 2010  TRUE  FALSE     FALSE FALSE
# 2 2011 FALSE  FALSE     FALSE FALSE
# 
# 
# $Tom
# $Tom$add
# [1] 2
# 
# $Tom$drop
# [1] 0
# 
# $Tom[[3]]
#     X1  Swim Volleyball Waterball
# 1 2010 FALSE       TRUE      TRUE
# 2 2011 FALSE      FALSE     FALSE
# 
#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use data.table to find the change in activities over the years grouped by individual:

```
DF <- structure(
    list(Year = c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
                  2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
                  2011, 2011), 
         Name = c("Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Mark", "Tom", 
                  "Rachale", "Rachale", "Rachale", "Mary", "Mary", "Mark", "Mark", 
                  "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Rachale", "Rachale", "Rachale", "Rachale", 
                  "Mary"), 
         Activity = c("Tennis", "Swim", "Basketball", "Volleyball", 
                      "Swim", "Tennis", "Waterball", "Yoga", "Volleyball", "Yoga", 
                      "Tennis", "Swim", "Volleyball", "Waterball", "Swim", "Tennis", 
                      "Waterball", "Yoga", "Swim", "Volleyball")), 
    .Names = c("Year", "Name", "Activity"), 
    row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
yearly_count <- DT[, .N, by = c('Name', 'Year')]
print(yearly_count)

change <- yearly_count[, list(change = diff(N)), by = Name]
print(change)
```

which results in the following output:

```
> print(yearly_count)
      Name Year N
1:    Mark 2010 4
2:     Tom 2010 1
3: Rachale 2010 3
4:    Mary 2010 2
5:    Mark 2011 2
6:     Tom 2011 3
7: Rachale 2011 4
8:    Mary 2011 1

> print(change)
      Name change
1:    Mark     -2
2:     Tom      2
3: Rachale      1
4:    Mary     -1
```

You only have 2 years in your data so there is only a single value representing the change from 2010 to 2011. Mark dropped 2 activities, Tom added 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code below adds a `value` column to mark 1 when a `Name` participates in an activity or zero if not, then adds a `Status` column to mark changes in `Activity`. In order to capture detailed structure in time-varying particpation in each `Activity`, the `Status` column is built with a long series of `ifelse` conditions. There's probably a simpler approach.

The `value` column is needed only to create the `Status` column and can be removed at the end of the process, but I've left it in for illustration.

The `Did not participate` value of `Status` marks cases where a person did not participate in the previous year and continued to not participate in the current year, while `Dropped` indicates a change from participation to non-participation.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat = dat %>%
  mutate(value=1) %>%
  complete(Activity, nesting(Year, Name), fill=list(value=0)) %>%
  arrange(Name, Activity, Year) %>%
  group_by(Name, Activity) %>%
  mutate(Status = ifelse(!lag(value) %in% 1 & value==1, "Added",
                    ifelse((!lag(value) %in% 0:1 & value==0) | all(value==0), "Did not participate",
                      ifelse(lag(value)==1 & value==1, "Continued", 
                        ifelse(lag(value)==1 & value==0, "Dropped", NA_character_)))))
```

> ```
>      Activity  Year   Name value              Status
> 1  Basketball  2010   Mark     1               Added
> 2  Basketball  2011   Mark     0             Dropped
> 3        Swim  2010   Mark     1               Added
> 4        Swim  2011   Mark     1           Continued
> 5      Tennis  2010   Mark     1               Added
> 6      Tennis  2011   Mark     1           Continued
> 7  Volleyball  2010   Mark     1               Added
> 8  Volleyball  2011   Mark     0             Dropped
> 9   Waterball  2010   Mark     0 Did not participate
> 10  Waterball  2011   Mark     0 Did not participate
> # ... with 38 more rows
> ```

Summarize activities by person by year:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(Year, Name, Status) %>%
  tally %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  complete(Status, nesting(Year, Name), fill=list(n=0)) %>%
  spread(Status, n) %>%
  arrange(Name, Year)
```

> ```
>    Year    Name Added Continued `Did not participate` Dropped
> 1  2010    Mark     4         0                     2       0
> 2  2011    Mark     0         2                     2       2
> 3  2010    Mary     2         0                     4       0
> 4  2011    Mary     0         1                     4       1
> 5  2010 Rachale     3         0                     3       0
> 6  2011 Rachale     1         3                     2       0
> 7  2010     Tom     1         0                     5       0
> 8  2011     Tom     2         1                     3       0
> ```